# Predicting an overflow when counting combinations

Tags: range, combinations, combinatorics

We have the following formula for determining how many combinations `C` we can pick of size `k` out of a set of `n`:

[image: Combinations Forumla]

I have written an algorithm which will always give an answer *if*, of course, the answer falls within the range of the datatype (`ulong`, in my case), by factorising and cancelling terms on the numerator and denominator during evaluation.

Even though it's quite fast to try to compute `C` and detect an overflow if the result is too large, it would be better if I could put `n` and `k` into a preliminary function which estimates whether the answer will be larger than what `ulong` can hold. It doesn't have to be exact. If it estimates that a given `n` and `k` will not overflow but it does, that's fine - but it should never say this it *will* overflow if it won't. Ideally this function should be very fast otherwise there is no point in having it - I may as well try and compute C directly and let it overflow.

I was plotting the curve of the nCk for various n's as a function of k to see if I can find a curve which grows at least as fast as C(n, k) but doesn't diverge too far in the range I'm interested in (0..2^64-1) and is computationally easy to evaluate.

I didn't have any luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual code for your algorithm, I can't give you a 100% solution, but your best bet is to develop a heuristic function.  By simply finding the smallest value of `r` for which the final answer to <sub>n</sub>C<sub>r</sub> overflows for a variety of n values, you should then be able to analyze the relationship between something like n and the ratio between n and r (<sup>n</sup>/<sub>r</sub>), and find a quick to calculate function which would let you know if overflow would occur via [regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis).

I found that for any `n < 68`, you should never overflow on the final answer, as <sub>67</sub>C<sub>33</sub> = <sub>67</sub>C<sub>34</sub> ~ 1.42x10<sup>19</sup> is the largest possible answer, and a `ulong` holds ~1.84x10<sup>19</sup>.  Similarly, when `n > 5000`, any `r > 5` or `n-r < n-5` will certainly overflow.  You can tune these cutoffs to your liking, and for all the n values in between them, just calculate <sup>n</sup>/<sub>r</sub> and use the regression formula to decide if it will overflow or not.

This might be too much work, but it should at least get you started on the right path.